# Google Plus Share sheet wrong Orientation Issue iOS iPad

Tags: ios, ios5, sdk, google-plus, landscape

Google Plus integrated using GooglePlus for iOS SDK v1.4.1, displays share sheet in wrong orientation in iPad iOS 5.0 with Landscape Orientation.

Have you guys observed this? Please reply with any fix or suggestions.

Cheers.

Comment: Were u able to get this issue resolved?

Comment: Yes, Just update the Google Plus SDK.

Comment: I'm using 1.4.1, the latest is v1.5.0 which requires iOS 6 or later. Any suggestions.

Comment: I tried it but it seemed to support for only 6.0 and above